# Differential geometry in hyperspace

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

After many years away from maths, I have recently started to dive into a subject I only ever learned the rudiments of: differential geometry, particularly helped by a brilliant series of lectures on youtube ([Lectures on Geometrical Anatomy of Theoretical Physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V49i_LM8B0E&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic) if you wish to check it out). This has set me thinking, though; a manifold is of course a topological space, and I wonder if there has been any work on exploring the possibility of somehow "lifting" at least parts of the differentiable structure into in a [hyperspace](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hyperspace) over the manifold. I haven't been able to find anything, so far - but then, what would one search for?

Comment: I have read the definition of hyperspace in topology. I was not familiar with it. However, I have this remark. Before talking about a differentiable structure, the topological space should first be a topological manifold, so that it must be second countable, Hausdorff and locally Euclidean. I have a feeling that hyperspaces over a manifold do not satisfy these conditions in general. I hope this helps.

Comment: Good points - so the question is under which conditions would that be? Another, potentially more interesting question, I think, is whether any of these could be relaxed somewhat, without making the construction meaningless or unworkable. One of the remarkable things about quantum mechanics is that there seems to be a certain degree of non-locality involved (like 'action at a distance') - could that be modeled in terms of the separation axions?

Comment: Regarding modelling non-locality in QM, it is perhaps better to create another post in the Physics section (expect to get a variety of different answers).

Comment: Oh, I don't know about talking to physicists; their main focus tends to be on the physics, and what I am interested in at the moment, is more the mathematical framework. I have felt quite frustrated over the years when trying to move beyond "QM as dogma" in discussions with physicists, but I feel strongly that it must be possible to device a mathematical framework from which the peculiarities of QM (and GR) can be derived rather than assumed a priory.

Comment: There is a number of mathematical formulations of QM, which are by now "classical". However, from what I understand, you are interested in understanding non-locality (or rather "deriving" it mathematically) within a Mathematical framework. I am not an expert on that, but since the EPR paper came out, there has been tons of papers written on the subject; in particular, the Bell inequalities are related to such discussions. Have some discussion with a Mathematically inclined Physicist. I am curious as to what they might say (and then maybe post it here, with their permission of course).

Comment: If I am wrong, maybe someone will correct me but... I think that the Poisson bracket in "classical mechanics" is defined using local operators. After quantization, the Poisson bracket gets replaced with the commutator of operators, and the commutator $[A,B] = AB-BA$ is not defined using local operators, so to speak. This may explain mathematically why "locality is lost, after quantization". Maybe you are looking for an explanation along these lines?

Comment: I have been brushing up on what I learned back in the day (and have discovered just how outadted my knowledge is), using youtube (search for Frederic Schuller, if you are interested); I still don't quite get how they justify the process of quantisation, but it seems clear that the so-called wave-function can only locally be described as a function from the space-time manifold into the complex numbers; globally it is "a section of the complex line-bundle"; I can't claim to understand fully what that means, but it certainly sounds great. Hopefully I will find out in time.

Comment: (Oops, I ran out of characters)

Comment: So to answer your question, my current intuition is that the non-locality we seem to see in QM, means that reality isn't as well-separated as we think. There must be some fuzzyness in the topology, I think; this 'spooky action at a distance' has the taste of lack of Hausdorff or something. On the other hand, there must also be some mechanism by which space looks like a smooth manifold when you don't look too closely, hence my interest in hyperspaces over smooth manifolds.